# MongoDB - Query on the last element of an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I know that MongoDB supports the syntax `find{array.0.field:"value"}`, but I specifically want to do this for the last element in the array, which means I don't know the index.  Is there some kind of operator for this, or am I out of luck?

EDIT:  To clarify, I want find() to only return documents where a field in the last element of an array matches a specific value.

Comment: What do your documents look like?

Comment: Well the array I'm trying to test is actually nested within another array, but I don't think that should have any effect.  Basically what I want to do is, in my find selector, only return documents where a particular field in the last element of an array matches a certain value.

Comment: You should look into [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), then play with `$unwind`, `$project`, `$match`, and `$group`

Comment: With the newest MongoDB, you can do this: `find({"array.-1.field":"value"})`

Comment: @MarsLee that doesn't work for me on version 4.2.0 - do you have any more information on that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I posted on the official Mongo Google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/m2XB6KYs8Fw), and got an answer from their staff.  It appears that what I'm looking for isn't possible.  I'm going to just use a different schema approach.

Answer (score 42):

In 3.2 this is possible. First project so that myField contains only the last element, and then match on myField.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { id: 1, myField: { $slice: [ "$myField", -1 ] } } },
   { $match: { myField: "myValue" } }
]);
```

Comment: in 3.2 there's the $arrayElemAt operator, which works with negative indices. so this can instead be `{ $project: { id: 1, myField: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$myField", -1 ] } } }`. I don't know if a slice with just one element is just as efficient

Comment: This outputs exactly what the question wanted.

Comment: Since MongoDB v3.4, there is also [$addFields operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) which means you no longer have to project individual fields.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

For scalar arrays

```
db.col.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$array", -1]}, value]}})
```

For embedded arrays - Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) expression with dot notation to project last element.

```
db.col.find({$expr: {$gt: [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$array.field", -1]}, value]}})
```

Spring `@Query` code

```
@Query("{$expr:{$gt:[{$arrayElemAt:[\"$array\", -1]}, ?0]}}")
ReturnType MethodName(ArgType arg);
```

Comment: For embedded arrays why do you use 0 and not -1?

Comment: This solution worked for me. 

I used for embedded arrays to check and see if a date inside the array itself is less than the current date. And if it's less than I update the document. 


 ```const query = {
    $expr: {
      $lt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$lessons.studentData.dueDate", -1] }, new Date()]
    }
  };
  const update = {
    completed: true
  };

  Class.updateMany(query, update)```

Comment: `db.col.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["array", -1]}, value]}})` threw an error for me. --> `db.col.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$array", -1]}, value]}})`

Answer (score 28):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation operator [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/) can be used to access the last element of an array:

---

For instance, within a `find` query:

```
// { "myArray": ["A", "B", "C"] }
// { "myArray": ["D"] }
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [{ $last: "$myArray" }, "C"] } })
// { "myArray": ["A", "B", "C"] }
```

---

Or within an `aggregation` query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { last: { $last: "$myArray" } } },
  { $match: { last: "C" } }
])
```

Answer (score 19):

use **$slice**.

```
db.collection.find( {}, { array_field: { $slice: -1 } } )
```

Editing:
You can make use of
 `{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }` to find a match.

But it won't give exactly what you are looking for. I don't think that is possible in mongoDB yet.

Comment: This just returns the last element, right?  That's not what I'm trying to do.  I want my find selector to only return documents where the last element of the array matches a certain value.

Comment: Just keep in mind that '$slice' return an array, while '$arrayElemAt' return an document (same sintax).

Answer (score 12):

**Version 3.6** use aggregation to achieve the same.

```
db.getCollection('deviceTrackerHistory').aggregate([
   {
     $match:{clientId:"12"}
   },
   {
     $project:
      {
         deviceId:1,
         recent: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$history", -1 ] }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`$position: 0`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) whenever you `$push`, and then always query `array.0` to get the most recently added element. Of course then, you wont be able to get the new "last" element.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but my application accesses Mongo using Spring Data, which at the time did not support pushing to the front of an array.  Not sure if it does now.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about performance, but this works well for me:

```js
db.getCollection('test').find(
  {
    $where: "this.someArray[this.someArray.length - 1] === 'pattern'"
  }
)
```

Comment: $where is very slow, because it runs javascript

Comment: Thank you very much! Might not be the most performant solution, but works like a charm for me. Not so slow for my data, maybe this performance difference is only perceptible within large datasets.

Comment: bad practice @eagleeye .

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this using aggregation.

```
model.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        lastArrayElement: {
          $slice: ["$array", -1],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "lastArrayElement.field": value,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Quick explanations. `aggregate` creates a pipeline of actions, executed sequentially, which is why it takes an array as parameter. First we use the `$addFields` pipeline stage. This is new in version 3.4, and basically means: *Keep all the existing fields of the document, but also add the following*. In our case we're adding `lastArrayElement` and defining it as the last element in the array called `array`. Next we perform a `$match` pipeline stage. The input to this is the output from the previous stage, which includes our new `lastArrayElement` field. Here we're saying that we only include documents where its field `field` has the value `value`.

Note that the resulting matching documents will include `lastArrayElement`. If for some reason you really don't want this, you could add a `$project` pipeline stage after `$match` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer use `$arrayElemAt`,if i want orderNumber:"12345" and the last element's value $gt than "value"? how to make the $expr? thanks！

For embedded arrays - Use `$arrayElemAt` expression with dot notation to project last element.

```
 db.col.find({$expr: {$gt: [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$array.field", -1]}, value]}})
```

Comment: Thank you for the editing; i tried a few times and i think i worked it out: ``` db.col.find({$expr:{$and:[{$gt: [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$array.field", -1]}, value]},{$eq:[{"$orderNumber"},"12345"]} ] }}) ```

Answer (score 0):

```html
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { 
      $and: [ 
        { $expr: { $eq: [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$fieldArray.name", -1] }, "value"] } }, 
        { $or: [] }
      ] 
    } 
  }
]);
```

Comment: Only select:

{ $project:  {"fieldArray": { $arrayElemAt: ["$fieldArray", -1] }} }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).