# MongoDB - Query on the last object of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any way in **MongoDB** in which I can specifically query on last object's key value in an array in a single db query.

For eg: This is my doc in a collection.

```
{
  "com" : [ 
    { "ts" : 1510830164203, "com" : "com1" }, 
    { "ts" : 1511242569673, "com" : "connected" },
    { "ts" : 1511244832741, "com" : "vb" } 
  ],
  "status" : [ 
    { "ts" : 1510857000000, "stat" : 3 } 
  ] 
}
```

So as you can see there are multiple objects in **com**.
How can I query on last object's ts(timestamp) or I want to check is last com inserted in between today's date or not.

I have already gone through this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array) But didn't find the appropriate solution.

Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` to get the last element and then match applied in `aggregation`. To get the last element using `$arrayElemAt` use second value `-1` that indicate last element of an array. `$arrayElemAt: ["arrayName", -1]`. code will be like

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      status: 1,
      com: {$arrayElemAt: ["$com", -1]}
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {"com.ts": 15115465465}
  }
])
```

N.B: if you want to compare like less than or greater than  then use like : `$lt, $lte, $gt, or $gte` any one that you need

```
$match: {"com.ts": {$lt: 15115465465}}
```

Comment: Yes, i think this can do the trick. But just tell me one thing. How heavy is this query? I mean I have to use this sort of query more frequently. I hope this won't cause any problem right?

Comment: Yes that's not heavy query, simple query

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = new Date( parseInt( "Today at 12:00 AM", 16 ) * 1000 )
var d2 = new Date( parseInt( "Tomorrow at 12:00 AM", 16 ) * 1000 )

db.table.find(
   { com: { $elemMatch: {ts:{ $gte: d1, $lt: d2 } } } })
)
```

Comment: Can we use it for the last object's key ? I mean it will search in the whole array.

Comment: No, I only need that object that satisfy condition on last object's key

Comment: The result will return all  objects that satisfy the condition of Today's date. Now you can make a max() aggregate to take the maximum ts (supposing the maximum has the highest value). Or you can apply the following:db.table.find(
   { com: { $elemMatch: {ts:{ $gte: d1, $lt: d2 } } } })
)sort({ts:-1}).limit(1)

Comment: Don't you think the above aggregate query will be more easier than this?

Comment: There is no easier, both are solutions to your question.

Comment: Ok, I think using aggregation will be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
             "_id" : ObjectId("5a197a3bde472b16ed9fc28d")
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$com"
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $sort: {
             'com.ts':-1
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $limit: 1
        }

    ]



);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below project query if you only need to find the last element.

```
db.collection.find({},{status: 1, com:{$slice: -1}})
```

More discussion on the similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Comment: More discussion on similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Comment: where is the discussion?

Comment: Please follow the hyperlink or use the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array