# how to get data in mongoose where last element in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to get data in mongoose where last element in array?
I have data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b56eb3deb869312d85a8e69"),
        "transactionStatus" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "pending",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "process",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b56eb3deb869312d8589765"),
        "transactionStatus" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "pending",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
            },
            {
                "status" : "process",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:03:30.347Z")
            },
            {
                "status" : "done",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:04:22.347Z")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And, I want to get data above where last object `transactionStatus.status = process`, so the result should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56eb3deb869312d85a8e69"),
    "transactionStatus" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "pending",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "process",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

how to do that with mongoose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Query on the last element of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Comment: please approve my answer if you like my efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) (MongoDB 3.6+) inside of match. Using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) passing `-1` as second argument you can get the last element as a temporary variable and then you can compare the values:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$transactionStatus", -1 ] } },
                    in: { $eq: [ "$$last.status", "process" ] } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The same result can be achieved for lower versions of MongoDB using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and `$match`. You can add `$project` then to remove that temporary field:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$transactionStatus", -1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "last.status": "process" }
    },
    {
        $project: { last: 0 }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, $addFields worked very well :)

Comment: this will take lot of time for thousands of record. Using my solution and find() method your performance will be improved

Comment: You're reordering `transactionStatus` which is far beyond the scope of this question and there's no information that you can do it. I'd assume that the order matters here

Comment: i am talking about efficiency when thousands of documents exist it will take lot of time than find() method

Answer (score 0):

//Always update new status at Position 0 using $position operator

```
db.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5b56eb3deb869312d85a8e69")
},
    {
        "$push": {
            "transactionStatus": {
                "$each": [
                    {
                        "status": "process",
                        "createdAt": ISODate("2018-07-24T09:02:53.347Z")
                    }
                ],
                "$position": 0
            }
        }
    }
)
```

//Your Query for checking first element **status is process**

```
db.find(
    {
        "transactionStatus.0.status": "process"
    }
)
```

refer [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/), [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)