# able to query specific index in array? mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example if I have below as my `documents`

```
{
    "field": [
        "hello",
        "random wording",
        {
            "otherId": 3232,
            "otherId2": 32332
        }
    ],
}
```

is it possible to let's say have a query that matches the `index 0` and `index 2`

I tried having query such as
`model.find({field: "hello")` which seem to work to query it.

But if I want to mix and match, let's say I want to make a query that matches whatever `index 0` and `index 2` or let's say in `index 2` the value is actually an `object` that I want to query all with `"otherId2": 32332`, instead that I need to match the whole `object`

Thanks in advance for any help or advises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query for a value exactly at an index **0** of array

```
model.find({'field.0': 'hello'})
```

Referencing array indexes works for the first-level array only.

Query by object property present at index **2** of array

```
model.find({'field.2.otherId': 3232})
```

Comment: thanks thanks, I tried something like `field[0]` :| was so close

Comment: Is there a way to query last index if I donot know the length of array?

Comment: @TayyabFerozi: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array