# how do i find last element of array list from MongoDB using aggregation function in spring?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb, slice

db.getCollection('notification').find({},{statusList:{$slice:-1}})
this query is getting expected outputs but from java, I could not find the solution for this. can anyone have a solution for this? I want to use only the aggregation function

Answer (score 0):

the aggregation operator $last can be used to access the last element of an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { last: { $last: "$yourArray" } } },
  { $match: { last: "C" } }
])
```

or

```
 db.getCollection('notification').aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         last: { statusList: [ "$slice", -1 ] }
      }
   }
])
```

and you can also take reference from:
[MongoDB - Query on the last element of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680295/mongodb-query-on-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`$last`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/#-last--array-operator-) aggregation operator.

```
 db.getCollection('notification').aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         _id: 0,
         last: { $last:"$statusList"}
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: whenever I use this I am getting this error, Error:
Uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$last'",
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, It gives the same output as $last:

```
 db.getCollection('notification').aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$project", -1 ] }
      }
   }
])
```